# Can’t load plist. Launchctl says "Invalid property list", tried plutil, SIP, permissions

Tags: macos, high-sierra, launchd, plist

I want to use the following plist to run a backup script under macos High Sierra.

File name: 
`com.pollux.backup.plist`

Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.pollux.backup.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
     <string>sh</string>
     <string>-c</string>
     <string>/bin/backup_pollux_server</string>
     <key>KeepAlive</key>
     </array>
     <key>RunAtLoad</key>
     <true/>
     <key>StartInterval</key>
     <integer>3600</integer>
     <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
     <string>/tmp/pollux_backup.err</string>
     <key>StandardOutPath</key>
     <string>/tmp/pollux_backup.out</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Permissions: `-rw-r--r--@ 1 root    wheel  694  3 Apr 19:57 com.pollux.backup.plist`

I use the same script and plist to backup my wife’s MacBook (Mavericks). It runs flawlessly. But when I try to load it with launchctl at my MacBook I get the following error message:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.pollux.backup.plist: Invalid property list
```

I checked the plist with plutil:

```
LaunchDaemons pollux$ plutil com.pollux.backup.plist
com.pollux.backup.plist: OK
```

xmllint just shows the content of the plist.

I switched off the SIP:

```
LaunchDaemons pollux$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

Does anyone have an idea what to try next?

Comment: Your Program Arguments shouldn't have a `<KeepAlive>` key as it's not an argument.  Also, you're calling a shell to run a script.  Why not just run a script?  Finally, why are you disabling SIP?  Have a look at this [launchd tutorial](https://www.launchd.info/)

Comment: @Allan, I disabled SIP because of that tutorial. It’s mentioned unter "Troubleshooting".

Comment: @klanomath, thanks a lot, changing the label helped. Do you have an idea why it still works under Mavericks?

Comment: Oh, no, it wasn’t the label. It was a missing `<true/>` for `KeepAlive`. Now it works. Thanks a lot erverybody!

Comment: @klanomath, I tried to do so, but I couldn’t figure out, how I can format code in comments. The code fences mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

The key *KeepAlive* had to be removed from the *ProgramArguments* array and properly enabled (`<true/>`).

This is how it works now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.pollux.backup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
     <string>sh</string>
     <string>-c</string>
     <string>/bin/backup_pollux_server</string>
     </array>
     <key>RunAtLoad</key>
     <true/>
     <key>KeepAlive</key>
     <true/>
     <key>StartInterval</key>
     <integer>3600</integer>
     <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
     <string>/tmp/pollux_backup.err</string>
     <key>StandardOutPath</key>
     <string>/tmp/pollux_backup.out</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: `<string>com.pollux.backup</string>` and `<string>com.pollux.backup.plist</string>` work. It makes no difference.